# Google consent screen. Permissions without refreshing page

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am using Gmail api and Google Calendar api in my project. I have issue with permission required for these apis.

**Requirements:** Assume I have not given any king of permission at this point.

1. If i am using Gmail api then it should ask only gmail related permission.
2. I i am using Calendar api then it should ask only calendar related permission.

It is working as per my requirement but there is one issue.

**Issue:** Suppose i have two buttons on same page, one for gmail and other for calendar.
I clicked first on gmail button, it prompts me to login and asks gmail related permissions, but instead of granting permission I cancled it, and clicked calendar button, here it is asking for gmail related permission only, once i refreshed the page, then it will ask for calendar permission.

**Question:** How can I make my website ask for correct permission without refreshing page.

I am using react-google-login npm.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of your application as a single entity.  It should only ask a user to login once.

If your app to run needs both gmail and google calendar permissions then you should be asking for both gmail and google calendar permissions.

That being said it is possible and sometimes worth wild to say request gmail scope and then if the user wants to use say another part of your application which requires calendar scopes to [request additional scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth)  the response from this should contain both the gmail and the calendar permissions but this is still going to require that the authorization window pop up and they consent to it.

**Answer**:  There is no way to request authorization of the user without showing them the consent screen and refreshing the access on your site.

Comment: I want to ask permission only when user wants to use that particular functionality. Say user want to add reminder or schedule task, then my app will ask if you want to add this to your calendar. At this point it makes sense to ask for calendar permission, and prompt use to login with appropriate permissions.

Comment: Everything is working fine. if we continue comment example, say user has given calendar permission, now he wants to use gmail functionality as well, when consent screen will pop up it should ask for calendar as well as gmail permissions at this point, but instead it is asking for calendar only permission. If i'll refresh page then it will start asking for both calendar and gmail permissions.

Comment: Then you should look into [incremental scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth) this way when the user needs calendar you will be abke to ask for calendar, which will include the already granted scope of gmail.  Its basically a way of adding additional permissions to the permissions you already have.